# DIV structure arrangement for an input field in MVC

Tags: html, css

I'm not a UI expert and attempting to achieve the below structure with html. the image is pretty much self explanatory of what i am after.

[image]

so far i have tried a few things but was unsuccessful and i have posted my mediocre attempt below. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<style>
    .field-wrapper{

    }
    .input-control-container
    {

    }
    .validation-message-container
    {

    }
    .help-icon-container
    {

    }
    .field-description-container
    {

    }
</style>
<div class="filed-wrapper">
    <div class="field-label-container">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="input-control-container">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <div class="field-description-container">
            Here goes the description
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="validation-message-container">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="help-icon-container">
        <img src="/help-icon.png" /> <!--help popup handle by JavaScript--->
    </div>
```

Comment: Your "attempt" contains no CSS.

Comment: @isherwood i tried a few float:left , float:right display:inline etc, just trial and error so left it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I whipped up a quick example of how to do this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf91vmv8/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="FormElement">
    <div>
        <label for="test">Feild Label</label>
        <input type="text" id="test" name="test" placeholder="Feild Input" />
        <i class="fa fa-question">Icon</i>
    </div>
    <p>
        Some description text here
    </p>
</div>
```

All I do is set all the objects in the sub-div of `.FormElement` to `display: inline-block`, and set their width to all be ~33% of the page. Then, I can align the text of the label to be near the center, and have a `<p>` at the bottom span the full width.

**CSS**

```
.FormElement label,
.FormElement input,
.FormElement i.fa
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}

.FormElement label
{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.FormElement p
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Note**

The `fa fa-question` in the `<i>` is an example [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon, so don't be thrown off by that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I might go about it:

```css
.field-outer {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.field-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
.field-wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
.input-control-container,
.field-label-container {
  text-align: right;
}
.help-icon-container {
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 40px;
}
.help-icon-container img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-outer">
  <div class="field-wrapper">
    <div class="field-label-container">
      <label for="blah">Label</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-control-container">
      <textarea id="blah">Textarea</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="help-icon-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" />
      <!--help popup handle by JavaScript--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-description-container">Here goes the description</div>
<div class="validation-message-container">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the width of your container or want it to auto, you can use `display: inline-block;`.

Check this layout:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
body * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.wrapper, .label-wrap, .input-wrap, .opt-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.input-wrap {
  width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
}
.input-wrap input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="label-wrap">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write here...">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="opt-wrap">
    <span>?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```